# Unable to send POST data of a form

Tags: c#, http-post, webclient

i have a problem with a Web Post Form.
I have download the page, I extrapolated the two required values (*form_build_id* and *form_token*), but once sent the POST the server does not receive anything in POST.

Excluded errors:

- Wrong link (can download the page).
- Incorrect extrapolated data (verified).
- Wrong string myParameters (verified).
- I have tested the Form manually and it work fine.

Some idea? There I slam my head for two days!

```
using (WebClientEx wc = new WebClientEx())
        {
            wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            string HTMLPage = wc.DownloadString(CREAT_TICKET_URL);

            string form_build_id    = SearchValue(HTMLPage, "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"form_build_id\"", "value=\"", "\"  />");
            string form_token       = SearchValue(HTMLPage, "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"form_token\"", "value=\"", "\"  />");

            string myParameters = "macchina=" + cmacExtID + "&utente=" + custExtID + "&oggetto=" + Title + "&body=" + Note + "&op=Conferma&form_build_id=" + form_build_id + "&form_token=" + form_token + "&form_id=app_form_new_ticket";

            string HtmlResult = wc.UploadString(CREAT_TICKET_URL, myParameters);
        }
```

> Note: WebClientEx class inherits WebClient. I used this approach to other forms such as login and work.

The final question is: if this approach is wrong, what is the best way to do this sequence of operations "download the page, extract the values from the HTML, send post form"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the header!
The header should be set for each call, while I thought it was enough to set only the first time.

```
using (WebClientEx wc = new WebClientEx())
    {
        wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        string HTMLPage = wc.DownloadString(CREAT_TICKET_URL);

        string form_build_id    = SearchValue(HTMLPage, "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"form_build_id\"", "value=\"", "\"  />");
        string form_token       = SearchValue(HTMLPage, "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"form_token\"", "value=\"", "\"  />");

        string myParameters = "macchina=" + cmacExtID + "&utente=" + custExtID + "&oggetto=" + Title + "&body=" + Note + "&op=Conferma&form_build_id=" + form_build_id + "&form_token=" + form_token + "&form_id=app_form_new_ticket";

        wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        string HtmlResult = wc.UploadString(CREAT_TICKET_URL, myParameters);
    }
```